# GLSL fragment shader output to memory

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Is it possible in OpenGLES2 to have a fragment shader output to memory?
This would be the ideal sequence:
1. texture in memory as input to fragment shader
2. fragment shader downsamples  the texture
3. fragment shader outputs the downsampled image directly as raw rgba to memory or alternatively into a texture

I'd prefer it to output directly to memory because I then need to process the downsampled image with an image recognition library in realtime and I'm aware that glReadPixels is too slow to be practical.

Comment: No, all data involved in a shader has to reside in GPU memory. The only scenario where this might be possible somehow is when GPU uses shared CPU memory. But you will probably not get enough control over it. The other option is doing the image recognition on the GPU as well if that is possible.

Comment: glReadPixels is mainly slow because everything has to stop while you wait for the GPU to finish. If you can live with a bit of latency, you could double/triple buffer everything, so that you're calling glReadPixels on an image that the GPU finished with on a previous frame. It might be fast enough that way.